# not added label to textField like right view

Tags: swift

I'm trying to add a label to the text field but nothing is displayed

```
  @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let my = UILabel()
    myLabel.text = "text"
    myLabel.textColor = .black
    myTextField.rightView = myLabel
    myTextField.rightViewMode = .always
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set sizeToFit(), in my case it's help

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a frame to the label such as `myLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 21))`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Textfield is behind the Label! Besides that it should be showing properly.